# Dismiss keyboard from inside objective C resignActive (UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification) double tapping on ipad home button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have tried to dismiss keyboard when user double press on home button, but failed to dismiss.

Basically I want to show splash screen in recent app tray when user double tap on home button. When there is no keyboard available the splash screen is showing correctly but when keyboard is there, view is not changed and not showing the splash screen.

Below code I have added its executing but not working for me.

In applicationWillResign

```
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
[searchBar endEditing:true];
```

in viewDidLoad

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(applicationWillResign)
 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
 object:NULL];
```

Comment: Soumen, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer, ok I'll try